# Axios POST request sends data to Express server but Error 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, axios

**Axios POST request sends data to Express sever but Error 404**

Hello, world, I am trying to build a user authentication server for a project I am working on, but I am running into a problem trying to send a POST request to my Node.js Express server.

I want to send a POST request using Axios containing a username and password from the browser. But once sending the request it gives me a *404 Not Found* error. The request has to go to `http://website/api/login` and my Node.js code should return either "authed" or "invalid". I tested the API inside Postman and that seems to be working. I also exported the request code from Postman and tested it with *fetch API*, *xhr*, and *Axios*, all returning the same result.

The server receives the data and handles it properly, but when I look in the Chromium debugger it appears that the *request URL* is just `http://website/` and not `http://website/api/login`. I am honestly lost and I have tried what feels like everything, but I can't seem to make it work. Any help in pointing me in the right direction would be amazing! Thank you!

The code I use for the POST request is:

```js
    const username = document.getElementById("username").value;
        const password = document.getElementById("password").value;

        const data = JSON.stringify({"username": username, "password":password});

        const config = {
            method: 'post',
            url: 'http://website/api/login',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            data : data
        };

        axios(config).then(function (response) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
```

This is what I see in the Chromium debugger:
[Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2FHG.png)

This is my Node.js / Express code:

```js
app.post('/api/login', function (req, res, next) {
    scriptFile.authUser(req.body, function (err, state) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else {
            if (state) {
                res.send("authed");
            } else {
                res.send("invalid");
            }
        }
    });
})
```

Thank you for any help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am stupid,

**Breakdown of what happened:**

Everything was working fine except that I put the input data and submit button inside a form, which will refresh the page...

I fixed it by changing the form to a div.

Answer (score -1):

Hey checking your chrome console pic looks like your post request is hitting the root api address 'http://website/' and not the full path 'http://website/api/login

Comment: Yes, I noticed, do you have any idea to fix it? I couldn't find a way.

Comment: try taking out method and url from your object.

Something like `
`axios.post('http://website/api/login', data, {headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }} ...`

Comment: Hi, yep I had already tried that, but just to be sure I tried it again, no luck, any ideas?